# Solving a non-linear ODE system with parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE system:

$$\begin{pmatrix} y_1(x)\\ y_2(x)\end{pmatrix}'= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} y_1(x)\\ y_2(x)\end{pmatrix} + \varepsilon \|y(x)\|^2 \begin{pmatrix} y_1(x)\\ y_2(x)\end{pmatrix}$$

where $\varepsilon$ is some real constant. I have shown, that $(0,0)$ is an attractor if $\varepsilon < 0$ and no attractor if $\varepsilon > 0$ by explicitely determining the solution. In my solutions, I divided by $\|y(x)\|$ and in the hints we have to this exercise, it is said, that $y(x) \neq 0$ for any real $x$. Somehow I do not see, why this is true. My idea is to use the existence and uniqueness theorem, since $y \equiv 0$ clearly solves this ODE system. So it breaks down to show, that the right hand side is Lipschitz continuous (if we define an appropriate function). However, I am not sure if that is the right way. Can anybody give me a hint, why $y \neq 0$ holds?

Comment: Why not to pass to polar coordinates? The equation for $z=y_1+iy_2$ is very simple: $\dot z=iz+\epsilon |z|^2z$.

Comment: @Artem Ah very nice. We did non cover complex differential equations in class. Does there an analogue version of Picard-Lindelöf hold?

Comment: You do not need any complex differential equations. Set $z(t)=r(t)e^{i\phi(t)}$ and get that $\dot \phi =1,\dot \rho=\epsilon \rho^3$, from where immediately all the details about the behavior follow.

Comment: @Artem Well, that is the faster way than I did. Very nice. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: the existence and uniqueness theorem does it.  The right side is obviously locally Lipschitz, in fact it's analytic.